# JavaFX: Optimized way to give nodes fixed width / dimension?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

How do I give all my buttons the same width? These buttons have a VBox as a container. First I tried setMaxWidth with max value which works well:

```
this.button1.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
this.button2.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
this.button3.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
this.button4.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

Ideally I would like to set this in my css file to keep my code clean from any design aspect. I find that there is an aweful lot of repetition going on here so how can I do this with 1 line of code? Something like:

```
.button {
  -fx-width: 50pt;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
.button {
    -fx-pref-width: 50px;
}
```

More details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm

> Selectors
>
> Several types of styles can be defined. Each type of style has its own
>   convention for selectors.
>
> Style classes correspond to class names. By convention, style class
>   names that consist of more than one word use a hyphen (-) between
>   words. Style class selectors are preceded by a dot (.).
>
> Examples of class selectors:
>
> .button .check-box .scroll-bar

The same for JavaFX 8. Check your code, mistake somewhere else.